# jquery Mobile - javascript stops working after navigating other page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile latest version.Everything works fine.I have some custom external and internal JS script.There is a jquery slideshow in the home page, it works well but when I navigate to another page and back to the home page by pressing back button or clicking any link, the slideshow stops working.

If I add in those link `data-ajax="false"` , then the slideshow works well in every case.But I don't want to use `data-ajax="false"` for quick response. How can I solve this problem? I am little bit new in jquery mobile.

Comment: Is your init in the `pageinit` event handler instead of the `$(document).ready` as mentioned [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html). That solved some of my init issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html) when you navigate between pages in jQuery Mobile the content is being reloaded by default. When you're using `data-ajax="false"` that forces jQuery Mobile to completely reload the page, so your scripts are working.

It seems that you have following slideshow call:

```
$(function(){
     // init gallery on DOM ready
     $('.gallery').slideshow();
});
```

But when you're using jQuery Mobile to navigate between pages you'll need to reinitialize your gallery when certain page reloaded, so the universal code will look like following:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
     // init gallery when current page loaded
     $('.gallery').slideshow();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.But your solution will fix internal JS issue.But the slideshow script comes as external script.
`<script src="js/jquery.refineslide.min.js"></script>`
How can I fix that?

Comment: Heh... Using such code you're loading plugin many times even if it is loaded in your current "browser session". F.e. you can make check that slideshow exists like: `if($.fn.slideshow)` inside `setInterval`, but I think it's better to use dependency manager (like requirejs), or add `refineslide.min.js` in global script.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[data-role=page]').page('destroy').page();
});
```

It should refresh your page and make everything work again.