# javascript stops working after adding jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple javascript that works, it is called when navigating to a page from a simple menu system. (I've omitted the menu for clarity of the problem)

```
    <label> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
          document.write(setupTitle); 
      </script>
    </label>
```

However, when I add jQuery and jQuery mobile scripts to the the head of the pages involved - the javascript above no longer works. I get the error message `"'referenceError : setupTitle is not defined."`

This has me confused.

The problem does not occur if I run the page directly - i.e. I don't go through the menu system. Which has led me to believe it was something to do with the init of the page.
Following the docs below:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/events.html
I tried wrapping the setup Title function inside the 
$(document).ready() function to no avail. I also tried the suggestion of destroying the page and trying a complete reload from a previous question of a similar thread : [jquery Mobile - javascript stops working after navigating other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544483/jquery-mobile-javascript-stops-working-after-navigating-other-page) which also didn't work:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('div[data-role=page]').page('destroy').page();
    });
```

Being new to JQuery / JQuery Mobile - normally I would power through as that is usually the best way to learn. but I'm running out of ideas and I'm clearly missing something fundamental! Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Kind Regards, 
Sam

Comment: do tou have `setupTitle` and if yes, where it is defined?

Comment: I do, as I said - the page works when running it directly.  This is stored in a separate .js file:     

    'function setupTitle()
    {
      var osceStation = "Cardiovascular OSCE";
      return osceStation;   
    }'

Included in the header using the line : 
'<script src ="js/htmlConstruct2.js"></script>' @Reflective

Comment: the error you receive means that at the moment of execution of line `document.write(setupTitle); ` setupTitle is not defined, so your aproach is not very correct. I'll post you an answer to try. just wait a bit.

Comment: can you setup a fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, the solution. It's to do with JQuery Mobile... It strips the head between HTML pages.

Found the solution here : 
[Jquery mobile href link dont load new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612625/jquery-mobile-href-link-dont-load-new-page) 
and here: 
http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/

Answer (score 1):

just to make your aproach correct, and avoid async errors change html of label to:

```
<label id="label1"></label>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#label1").html(setupTitle());
});
```

and asure that `setupTitle` is defined as main function.

Comment: Thanks for your response Reflective, to clarify, what do you mean by making setupTitle a main function?

Comment: defined as general funtion i.e. in window ... so if you can access it as `window.setupTitle();` ... if accessible in that way you can be 100% sure it is general (main) function.

Comment: Defining a general function isn't something you have to do explicitly though is it? You simply declare 'function (a,b) { };' though correct? I've made the changes you have suggested, Still no joy.